# Best way to start desktop application development for a web developer

Tags: desktop-application

I'm a web developer right now and I do that professionally. (PHP/MySQL/JavaScript) (Java/MySQL/Javascript) (RoR)

I make some scripts and sell them too.

Now I'd like to add desktop application development to my repertoire.

What languages/frameworks would suit me? I would ideally like to learn and get ready to code a few software and sell them.

You could possibly say Rapid Application Development(RAD) methodology suits me. So please suggest languages/frameworks that can complement RAD more easily.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080490/web-developer-wants-to-learn-desktop-programming

Answer (score 0):

Try out [RealBasic](http://www.realbasic.com) it's really basic and it's RAD, Rapid Application Development platform

Also it's cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Consider programming for iOS 5? It's a refreshing change from the web, and the story board style development is definitely RAD.

You can easily deploy to the app store too and start making money.

Maybe here would have more answers too? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As web developer if you have programmed in Flash/Actionscipt then you can develop desktop applications using the Adobe AIR runtime. Even if you don't know Actionscript you shall be up and running because I assume you known Javascript and Actionscript is very similar. The advantages of beginning with Flash/Actionscript over every other platform are:

- Simple and Easy
- Very extensive still not bloated ready to use API that comes inbuilt
- Visual emphasis
- As web developer UI is major development area and Flash similar to web
  offers fine control over creating UI and not just some standard
  collection of controls. You can very easily create custom and rich 
  interactions, visuals and user experiences, its fun esp if you are a visual and creative person.

I suggest you try to build a simple game on your own as a learning experience following any of the many available tutorials on youtube. You will easily and naturally pickup object oriented programming cuz game dev requires it and cuz games have real objects that are easy to understand without much abstraction. I also suggest video tutorials from Lynda.com: just watch and absorb compared to a book, books are good for reference though. In 2 weeks or so you should be productive. All the best!